# What is the equivalent SQL Server data type for Access attachment?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I can't seem to find the best answer for this one. Access offers a great feature when it comes to attaching a file only if your database is within access itself. But due to security reasons, I'm storing the data in SQL Server and I used a `varbinary(max)` for files.

Upon linking the tables from SQL Server to Access, the `varbinary(max)` was read as an OLE object. With this I can't seem to attach a file to the Access component it was bounded to. I've read tutorials sayings that I need to create a function to read the binary representation of OLE object.

Moreover, this is not the kind of feature I've wanted to because I don't want to make use of OLE object since data are stored in SQL server which is very heavy. I really want to utilize the benefits of Access attachments since it just referenced to the file systems by implementing it in SQL server also.

But I couldn't figured out how to. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent in SQL server to attachment fields (just like there are none for multi-valued fields), because these types are actually a subtable to store the data (that's why you can add multiple attachments in one field).

It sounds like you don't understand what the attachment type does, by the way. Attachments attached using the attachment type are stored in the database, and not linked in any way, so *it just referenced to the file systems* is probably untrue.

Comment: One could use the SQL Server FileTable feature, which stores files (attachments) in the database and optionally allows access via a file share too. Some reengineering of the Access app would be needed to go down that path, though.

Comment: You can use attachments that point to a standard file, OR you can embed the attachments - so both "linked" or "embed" choices are available . At the end of the day, when possible it certainly far better to store the path name. Of course with SQL server - especially a cloud based version, then some compelling reasons do exist to store the document in a table as opposed to on the file system. So WHEN possible I certainly admit that using the file system and keeping files out of the database system is a far better choice - but some needs and exceptions do exist when use of file not a choice.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal could you please elaborate on how (e.g. provide a link)? We're both talking about the attachment field type, right? Because the OP specifies he doesn't want to use OLE objects.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I admit I'm wrong with the idea that attachments types just referenced to the file systems. It's just an intuition anyways. And I agree with you that I don't want to use OLE objects to store this kind of data.

Comment: As I stated, the attachment type has two options (link or embed). If you use a link, then for SQL server you simply create a child table and store the path name to the file location - you can build a form that looks near identical in operation to the built in dialogs in less then 1 hour of time. So just store the  link/path to the plane jane file in a plane jane text column in SQL server. Really a easy process. The other option of storing the actual file in a sql server column difficult but can be done, but you need code to read the file as binary, and then save the blob into the column.

Comment: As noted, I don't recommend storing the actual file in SQL server - but as noted there certainly some "use" cases that can benefit from such a approach. So just store a link to the file in a plane jane SQL column. You can use VBA application.FollowHyperlink to launch any windows file with a associated extension with 1 line of VBA code.

Comment: I believe you're confusing the attachment type, and OLE objects

Comment: Not sure if you mean me in regards to attachment vs OLE. I am talking about the attachment type. I migrated applications with attachment data types. And in fact I done this for BOTH types of attachments (embedded and linked). For the embedded, we simply wrote VBA code to save out all files to a folder structure (so we converted everything to linked). Linked is FAR better choice then locking up all the files in the database. External files work with web server, and even just searching document text etc. can be done via windows. One REALLY wants to avoid storing files in SQL server if possible.

Comment: You thus simply covert the attachment type in Access to plane Jane columns with a plane Jane column that holds the link. You then migrate that to SQL server. So the converting of the attachment type to regular column with a link/path to the file is to occur before you migrate to SQL server. As I stated, you can “emulate” the attachment process since you have a built in File Dialog to browse to select a file, and you have application.Followhyperlink that allows launching of any file with one line of VBA code. Until you decide if linked file are ok, then what I suggest is not of use.